# Why am i getting terminating error from xml web server response to iOS?

Tags: ios, xml, web-services

Im getting a response like this:

```
2013-04-22 15:38:38:693 Some[963:3079] __36-[SDAFParseAPIClient getDataFromWeb]_block_invoke [Line 88] parsing
2013-04-22 15:38:38:694 Some[963:3079] -[SDAFParseAPIClient parser:didStartElement:namespaceURI:qualifiedName:attributes:] [Line 64] Element started string
2013-04-22 15:38:38:695 Some[963:3079] -[SDAFParseAPIClient parser:foundCharacters:] [Line 78] The characters are { "recordcount": "62", "data": [ { "Codigo": "1", "NombrePublico": "Super Stor
2013-04-22 15:38:38:696 Some[963:3079] -[SDAFParseAPIClient parser:foundCharacters:] [Line 80] The page numbers are (null)
2013-04-22 15:38:38:698 Some[963:3079] -[SDAFParseAPIClient parser:foundCharacters:] [Line 78] The characters are es", "Horario": "LV:8:00 AM - 6:30 PM,S:8:00 AM - 5:00 PM,D:-", "Direccion": "6 Ave., 5 Calle, S.O. Bo. El", "Telefono": "2556-1242", "Coordenadas": "16.502917616794166,-85.02710920572281", "Ciudad": "SAN PEDRO SULA" }, { "Codigo": "2", "NombrePublico": "Some 3 Ave.", "Horario":
2013-04-22 15:38:39.571 Some[963:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'data parameter is nil'
```

Here is my code:

```
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict{

    NSLog(@"Element started %@",elementName);
    self.currentElement=elementName;

}

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName{

    NSLog(@"Element ended %@",elementName);
    self.currentElement=@"";

}

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string{
    if([self.currentElement isEqualToString:@"string"]){
        NSLog(@"The characters are %@",string);
        id data = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[string dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding] options:0 error:nil];
        NSLog(@"The page numbers are %@",[[[data valueForKey:@"List"] objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"PageNumber"]);
    }
}

-(void)getDataFromWeb{
    NSURL *feedURL = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://someserver.com?Cli_Cod=1&Key_String=34uhg934hg389j"];
    NSURLRequest *feedRequest = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:feedURL];
    AFXMLRequestOperation *feedOperation = [AFXMLRequestOperation XMLParserRequestOperationWithRequest:feedRequest success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSXMLParser *XMLParser) {
        NSLog(@"parsing");
        [XMLParser setDelegate:self];
        [XMLParser parse];
    } failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, NSXMLParser *XMLParser) {
        UIAlertView *connectionError = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Connection Error" message:error.localizedDescription delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [connectionError show];
    }];
    [feedOperation start];
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Your code assumes that `foundCharacters` will only be called once for a given tag. From the log output this is not true.

In your `didStartElement`, initialize a mutable string. Append to this mutable string in the `foundCharacters` method.

Then in the `didEndElement` method, parse the one big mutable string (if the end element is for the `string` element).

This is what I would do:

Add a private property: `@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableString *currentValue;`

Then update your methods:

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict {
    NSLog(@"Element started %@",elementName);
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"string"]) {
        self.currentElement = elementName;
        self.currentValue = [NSMutableString string];
    }
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName {
    NSLog(@"Element ended %@",elementName);
    if ([self.currentElement isEqualToString:@"string"]) {
        NSLog(@"The characters are %@", self.currentValue);
        id data = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[self.currentValue dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding] options:0 error:nil];
        NSLog(@"The page numbers are %@", [[[data valueForKey:@"List"] objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"PageNumber"]);
    }

    self.currentElement = nil;
    self.currentValue = nil;
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string{
    if (self.currentValue) {
        [self.currentValue appendString:string];
    }
}
```

Comment: Like this?:...
'
// XMLParser.m
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string {
  if (!currentElementValue) {
     // init the ad hoc string with the value     
     currentElementValue = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:string];
  } else {
     // append value to the ad hoc string    
    [currentElementValue appendString:string];
  }
  NSLog(@"Processing value for : %@", string);
}  

...'

Comment: See my updated answer. BTW - it's really hard to read that much code in a comment.

Comment: Thx but I still get a termination error in the console: `[SDAFParseAPIClient parser:didStartElement:namespaceURI:qualifiedName:attributes:] [Line 64] Element started string
[SDAFParseAPIClient parser:didEndElement:namespaceURI:qualifiedName:] [Line 74] Element ended string
[SDAFParseAPIClient parser:didEndElement:namespaceURI:qualifiedName:] [Line 76] The characters are { "recordcount": "62","Direccion": "1ra calle. Salida a la Lima, a la p
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'data parameter is nil` How can i format code in a comment?

Comment: Does the log message for `self.currentValue` show all of the JSON string or just part of it? IF just part, you need to figure out why. Use the debugger and step through the code.

Comment: Yes it shows a lot of the json returned and its good but its missing about the last 5 entries or so.  It stops at this line: `        self.valuesDictionary  = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[self.currentValue dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding] options:0 error:nil];
`

Comment: i just noticed there is a ´ somewhat close to where the parsing stops.  How do I handle this?